# why ttcIndex and fontvariantSetting not found in cordova build?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-availability": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^4.9.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-analytics": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^4.12.2",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.12.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/sim": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^4.9.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "com.lampa.startapp": "^6.1.6",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-play-services-version-adapter": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.0.6",
    "cordova-plugin-analytics": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-appavailability": "0.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.10",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "git+https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-sim": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-video-player": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.4",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-soap": "^0.2.2-beta6",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.8",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
```

Issue not solve by adding configure strategy or the plugin for support android.
 AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
in values.xml file.
and failed linking references. issue

Support library plugin tried,
configuration strategy

Comment: Set your `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or higher.

Comment: Where do you set the compileSdkVersion?

Comment: I m edited the question the package.json file dependancies which is might be causing issue pls help me with a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is because on June 17, Google Updated Play Services and Firebase SDK requirements, a quick fix is edit `project.properties` on platforms/android folder and modify any lines that matches:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-*
```

and change the version to `11.8.0` to make it work.

Example:

```
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
```

Change to:

```
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
```

And build again.
To make it work this way you should use cordova-android 7 or 8.

Another fix is upgrade the compileSdkVersion to 28.

Comment: that does solve but need to fix some others as well

Comment: just like android adapter and androidX